# How have linear graph with BarChart google api

Tags: google-visualization

I want to display some vote from people, I would like to accept only non decimal values on the horizontal axis and make it linear (should be the default behaviour and I think it's but not from zero, it's linear from 1 in my application...

Here is the source code for haxis configuration.

```
hAxis: {
      title: t('shared.new_top_bar.votes'),
      # Don't display negative values
      min_value: 0,
      gridlines: {
          #color: '#878787',
          count: -1
      }
  }
```

For the moment I got that:
[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh1Db.png

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't add the image because of the reputation...

Comment: I fixed the decimal thing with: gridlines: {
                  count: data_votes[data_votes.max()]
              }
to force it to take the max value as gridline number.
But still the problem about the linearity...

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want the hAxis to start at 1 instead of 0?  Set the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` value to `1`.

Comment: Actually no, I just want the space between the 0 and the 1 be the same than between the 1 and the 2, etc. it\s not the case here, that should be the same distance between each value, something linear!

Comment: The spacing is the same, its just that your "VoteMany" chart isn't starting at 0.  Set the `hAxis.viewWindow.min` value to `0` to fix.

Comment: The only problem is that I don't have the number in the hAxis anymore... Trying to find a way but I found nothing so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I post what I did to help next people:

```
{
      width: 550,
      height: 200,
      #colors: @colors,
      title: vote.question,
      backgroundColor: {
          fill:'transparent'
      },
      is3D: true,
      # Displays items even if the value is 0
      sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
      legend: {
          alignment: 'center'
      },
      animation: {
          duration: 1000,
          easing: 'out'
      },
      # Don\t display decimal values.
      hAxis: {
          title: t('shared.new_top_bar.votes'),
          # Don't display negative values
          gridlines: {
              count: data_votes.max() + 1# 0 count!
          },
          viewWindow: {
              min: 0,
              max: data_votes.max()
          }
      }
  }
```

The hAxis is calculated because I wanted only decimal value and I had to do it explicitly.